# Allow node module relying on uuid() to execute in client and server

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, uuid

I have a node module that I am building, and I want it to be able to execute on the server (in nextjs server side rendering) and the client (call additional lifecycle methods in the UI).  This same module also needs to work when used purely as a js library that can be included in a `<script>` tag on the page.  This module depends on the uuid module, which has logic in it to check if it is running in a browser or server context, and use the proper random number generators/crypto libraries that are available in that context.

If I don't specify a target in my webpack config, the bundle works great in a client browser.  It includes the webpack browser logic just fine.  But it doesn't work in the server case - webpack removed the server capable logic in the `uuid` module.

If I `target: 'node'` in my webpack config - it executes just fine as a node module on the server and the client.  It seemingly included all of the logic this time.  But now it doesn't work if included just as a script tag on the page. I get `ReferenceError: require is not defined` from the file that depends on the `uuid` module.

It seems like the `uuid` module should handle these different environments just fine, but webpack is messing with that.  How can I let that module resolve the proper implementation at runtime?

I unfortunately do not have a minimally reproducible example, or additional code to share at this time.  I figured someone might have run into this with webpack (or even webpack and the `uuid` module) and know the solution.

Comment: You need two distinct webpack config files. For example: client.config.js and server.config.js

Comment: Yeah I know I can accomplish it with two dfiferent config files, the question was if its possible to have a single webpack config to accomplish this.  I think probably not

Comment: hmm maybe this https://github.com/developit/microbundle

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do this by building a single version of the package, but I don't think that is possible.

What is possible is building multiple versions, and then hosting the web bundle via unpkg or jsdelivr via an entry in package.json.  Those entries can point to the `target: 'web'` version of the package, while the npm package can point to the `target: 'node'` version.